# Android: Variable columns for gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I'd like to create a gridview with variable columns, say,

row 1, 2 columns

row 2, 3 columns

row 3, 2 columns

row 4, ...

And I also can have them keep same vertical/horizontal spaceing

I fount this [StaggeredGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436359/android-column-gridview-variable-width-like-googleplus-app) but didn't likely fit my need. How could I layout such a gridview? thanks.

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133456/using-etsy-android-staggered-gridview

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia, I noticed this lib, but it said 'An Android staggered grid view which supports multiple columns with rows of varying sizes', I didn't find any hint how to support variable columns